# How to print year sign in DateTimeFormatter when the count of letters is four?

Tags: java, datetime-format, java-time, datetimeformatter

From `DateTimeFormatter` [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

> If the count of letters is less than four (but not two), then the sign
> is only output for negative years as per SignStyle.NORMAL. Otherwise,
> the sign is output if the pad width is exceeded, as per
> SignStyle.EXCEEDS_PAD.

From what I understand, if the pad width is not exceeded and the count of letters is four, the minus sign (for negative years) should not be printed during formatting.

So I wrote such a snippet of code (figuring that I cannot use '`y`' because then the year will always be positive):

```
    var negativeDate = LocalDate.now().minus(2021, ChronoUnit.YEARS);
    var formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ppppuuuu");
    var text = negativeDate.format(formatter);
    System.out.println("formatted string: " + text);
```

This code throws `DateTimeException`: "*Cannot print as output of 5 characters exceeds pad width of 4*".

So my question is basically **how to see this last sentence from the javadoc work**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Otherwise* in the sentence you are asking about refers to the situation where the count of letters is 4 or greater. Confusingly the *pad width* here has nothing to do with pattern letter `p` for padding. It refers to the number of digits to be printed. It refers back to the first sentence of the paragraph, *The count of letters determines the minimum field width below which padding is used.*

So to see that work, use 4 or more pattern letters and use a year that takes a greater number of digits than the number of pattern letters. It works with both `u`, `y` and `Y`.

```
    DateTimeFormatter uuuu = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu");
    DateTimeFormatter yyyy = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy");
    DateTimeFormatter uppercaseYyyy = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY");
    
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of(12345, Month.OCTOBER, 23);
    
    System.out.println(ld.format(uuuu));
    System.out.println(ld.format(yyyy));
    System.out.println(ld.format(uppercaseYyyy));
```

Output:

> ```
> +12345
> +12345
> +12345
> ```

The minus sign is printed regardless of the number of characters to be printed. The documentation of `SignStyle.EXCEEDS_PAD` says:

> … A negative value will always output the '-' sign.

**Documentation link:** [`SignStyle.EXCEEDS_PAD`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/SignStyle.html#EXCEEDS_PAD)

Answer (score 0):

> If the count of letters is less than four (but not two), then the sign
> is only output for negative years as per SignStyle.NORMAL.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var negativeDate = LocalDate.now().minus(2021, ChronoUnit.YEARS);
        var formatter1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ppuu");
        var formatter2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ppu");
        var text1 = negativeDate.format(formatter1);
        var text2 = negativeDate.format(formatter2);
        System.out.println("formatted string: year" + text1);
        System.out.println("formatted string: year" + text2);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
formatted string: year01
formatted string: year-1
```

I have used `uu` (count of letters as two) in `formatter1` and therefore it does not show a negative sign. However, if the count of letters is is less than four, but not two, you need to provide enough padding e.g. for the year, `-1`, you need padding of at least `2` (i.e. `pp`), one for the `-` sign and one for `1`. If you provide less number of padding, you will get `DateTimeException` and if you provide more than `2` padding, you will get space before `-1`.

Thus, in case of the format `uuuu`, you need a padding of at least `5` (i.e. `ppppp`) for a negative year,  one for `-` and `4` for years (`0001`) i.e. you need to use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("pppppuuuu")` to avoid `DateTimeException`.

Comment: this does not answer my question ("how to see this last sentence from the javadoc work") - so the "otherwise" case with 4 letters

Answer (score 0):

This pattern `"ppppuuuu"` defines `padWidth` of 4 applied to the following format `uuuu`, which applies `SignStyle.EXCEEDS_PAD` (according to [javadoc for `DateTimeFormatBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html)).

That is, the `-` is always printed due to current `SignStyle`.

Thus, when the formatter tries to print a negative year, it uses 4 digits and a sign thus exceeding the available `padWidth`.

Similarly, the sign is *always* printed when using `u` or `uuu` patterns because `SignStyle.NORMAL` is applied in these cases.

So, the sign won't be printed only when `uu` format is used.

To avoid the exception for a negative number, the padding should exceed the number of digits, for example, `"ppppu"` or `"pppppuuuu"`.

```java
var onlyU = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu");
var padded = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ppppu");
var padded5 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("pppppuuuu");

for (LocalDate d = LocalDate.now().minus(2421, ChronoUnit.YEARS); d.getYear() < 2200; d = d.plus(400, ChronoUnit.YEARS)) {

    try {
        var uuuu  = d.format(onlyU);
        var ppppu = d.format(padded);
        var pppppuuuu = d.format(padded5);

        System.out.printf("formatted year=%5d\tuuuu=[%s] \tppppu=[%s]\tpppppuuuu=[%s]%n", d.getYear(), uuuu, ppppu, pppppuuuu);

    } catch (DateTimeException e) {
        System.out.println("error: " + e);  
    }
}
```

Output:

```
formatted year= -401    uuuu=[-0401]    ppppu=[-401]    pppppuuuu=[-0401]
formatted year=   -1    uuuu=[-0001]    ppppu=[  -1]    pppppuuuu=[-0001]
formatted year=  399    uuuu=[0399]     ppppu=[ 399]    pppppuuuu=[ 0399]
formatted year=  799    uuuu=[0799]     ppppu=[ 799]    pppppuuuu=[ 0799]
formatted year= 1199    uuuu=[1199]     ppppu=[1199]    pppppuuuu=[ 1199]
formatted year= 1599    uuuu=[1599]     ppppu=[1599]    pppppuuuu=[ 1599]
formatted year= 1999    uuuu=[1999]     ppppu=[1999]    pppppuuuu=[ 1999]
```

Comment: thanks, but your answer does not really explain the difference between less-than-four and four-or-more count of letters ("otherwise" in the question)

Comment: Excuse me, my answer perfectly explains the reason of the `DateTimeException` when `ppppuuuu` format is used, due to applying `SignStyle.EXCEED_PAD`.  Currently accepted answer does not contain any patterns with padding. Whatever...

Comment: yeah! but please consider what was my original question! I started playing with this p's in pattern only because I misunderstood the explanation from the **last quoted sentence**. I appreciate your effort, it's just it's not what I was searching for - and this was so complicated for me that I even forgot what I meant originally :) only this today's answer reminded me. maybe someone else will find it useful. cheers